# Issues with tail recursion in file operations(C#)

Tags: c#, file, recursion, directory, stack-overflow

I'm writing a program to find all files of a type on a computer(currently image files) and I'm using tail recursion to search directories in this fashion:

```
private void ImageSearchByDir(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
     //search for images by directory, later display them with this method when I get basic search working
     foreach (var f in dir.GetFiles())
     {
         //add file info to current list
         this.myfiles.Add(f);
     }

     foreach (var d in dir.GetDirectories())
     {
         //recursive call to iterate through subdirectories
         ImageSearchByDir(d);
     }
}
```

The issue seems to arise when searching directories with large amounts of files. For example, I searched a folder with ~700 images housed under 3 levels of folders with no issue, but attempting to search my desktop crashes the program. I assume this has something to do with the recursion and the resulting stack size, and I'd like to implement a more elegant solution if possible(I have read up on trampolining but I'm not 100% sure that will fix this).

Comment: 1) What kind of exception did you receive? 2) Probably enough to collect only file name as _string_, but not as _FileInfo_?

Comment: What you are doing is recursion but does not qualify as tail recursion.  Tail recursion would require that there are no additional operations in the function after calling itself.  In your case, the foreach loop must run its check for more items after each recursive call, making this non-tail-recursive.   Luiso's answer gives a way to do this without recursion at all.

Comment: In reply to Jackdaw I receive no error, the program simply stays stuck in a loading state(white background, blue windows loading circle for cursor, clicking it flags it as 'Not responding'). And Gideon you make a good point, sorry if my wording was misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Queue` and do your work like this:

```
class ImageSearcher
{
    private Queue<DirectoryInfo> found = new Queue<...>();

    public void ImageSearchByDir(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
         found.Enqueue(dir);
         RealSearch();
    }

    private void RealSearch()
    {
         while(found.Count > 0)
         {
             var current = found.Dequeue()

             // do your filtering on the current folder

             // then add the children directories
             foreach(dir in current.GetDirectories())
             {
                 found.Enqueue(dir);
             }
         }  
    }
}
```

this way you don't have recursion, if that's what you think is troubling you

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a go and update you soon.

Comment: Good news is your solution fits seamlessly into my previous code. Bad news is I'm still having the same issue, so I'm gonna play with it a bit more. Using a queue seems like a great start though and I appreciate the nudge forward.

Comment: So your issue remain, meaning it wasn't recursion related. Based on @Jackdaw's comment you could have `Queue<string>` and use that list folders and files using `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories` and `..Enumerate.EnumerateFiles` which both take a `string path`.